# Email mystery - CC'ed email is delayed

Tags: email, hosting

I am trying to solve some email issues that I am currently experiencing. I work for this company that periodically sends out emails from Taiwan, and it is CC'ed to 2 email accounts, my work email (in the US) and to one that is hosted by 1&1 server (not sure where is this located).

The problem is the emails received on the 1&1 server, specifically from Taiwan, are delayed 1-2 days, and are sent in groups of 2 or more at once instead of one-by-one as they come in. Meanwhile, I am receiving it at my work email just fine and on time. I've tried sending test emails to the 1&1 email address, and it is received immediately.

I have checked with both Taiwan side and 1&1 side, and they both say they are not experiencing problems / delays. Can anyone help me solve this mystery? Where else can I look into?

### Addendum:

This is the email header:

```
Return-Path: <[Taiwan Email]> 
Delivery-Date: Tue, 21 Jun 2011 12:17:45 -0400 
Received: from localhost.localdomain ([218.32.192.116]) by mx.perfora.net (node=mxus1) with ESMTP (Nemesis) id [] for []; Tue, 21 Jun 2011 12:17:45 -0400 
Received: from [] (viaweb01 [IP]) by localhost.localdomain (IP) with ESMTP id ; Tue, 21 Jun 2011 01:08:28 +0800 
Message-ID: <[message id]> 
Date: Tue, 21 Jun 2011 01:08:28 +0800 (CST) 
From:[Taiwan Email] 
To: [work email] 
Subject: [subject line] 
Cc: [1&1 email] 
Mime-Version: 1.0 
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert at this, but I believe you can view the email headers and look at the `Received:` nodes to see the servers that are handling the email relay, and look at the timestamps to see where it gets hung up.

Comment: This is what I have so far:

Return-Path: <[Taiwan Email]>
Delivery-Date: Tue, 21 Jun 2011 12:17:45 -0400
Received: from localhost.localdomain ([])
 by mx.perfora.net (node=mxus1) with ESMTP (Nemesis)
 id [] for []; Tue, 21 Jun 2011 12:17:45 -0400
Received: from [] (viaweb01 [IP])
 by localhost.localdomain (IP) with ESMTP id ;
 Tue, 21 Jun 2011 01:08:28 +0800
Message-ID: <[message id]>
Date: Tue, 21 Jun 2011 01:08:28 +0800 (CST)
From:[Taiwan Email]
To: [work email]
Subject: [subject line]
Cc: [1&1 email]
Mime-Version: 1.0

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the timestamps in the headers of one of the affected emails to see where the delay is occurring. You can then address it with that entity.

Comment: This is the email header:
`Return-Path: <[Taiwan Email]>
Delivery-Date: Tue, 21 Jun 2011 12:17:45 -0400
Received: from localhost.localdomain ([218.32.192.116])
 by mx.perfora.net (node=mxus1) with ESMTP (Nemesis)
 id [] for []; Tue, 21 Jun 2011 12:17:45 -0400
Received: from [] (viaweb01 [IP])
 by localhost.localdomain (IP) with ESMTP id ;
 Tue, 21 Jun 2011 01:08:28 +0800
Message-ID: <[message id]>
Date: Tue, 21 Jun 2011 01:08:28 +0800 (CST)
From:[Taiwan Email]
To: [work email]
Subject: [subject line]
Cc: [1&1 email]
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; 

`

Comment: This email was received by 1&1 on Tuesday 6/21/2011 9:18am PST, but received on my work email on Monday 6/20/2011 at 10:09 AM PST

Comment: That's probably due to the International date line. Identifying the GMT offsets will help in translating the timing to a common reference.

Comment: Well, I checked the email headers for the same email, sent to my work email and to the 1&1 hosting company. The email sent to 1&1 is received a day late. So could it be 1&1's problem?

Comment: If it's receieved at 1&1 a day late then I'd say it's not 1&1's fault. How can it be their fault if it arrives there a day late?

Comment: So, I checked with Taiwan's side, and apparently they received this message: 
`The original message was received at Tue, 28 Jun 2011 12:10:25 +0800 from  [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]

   ----- Transcript of session follows -----
451 4.4.1 reply: read error from mx00.1and1.com.
451 4.4.1 reply: read error from mx01.1and1.com.
<xxx@xxx.com>... Deferred: Connection reset by mx01.1and1.com.
Warning: message still undelivered after 4 hours Will keep trying until message is 5 days old`
I added the email address to the whitelist so it's not a spam thing.. What could be the problem still?

Comment: @joeqwerty: Any thoughts?